# Magento2 upgrade fail

Tags: magento2, upgrade, version

I have installed Magento 2.0 CE from archive. When I try to update the Magento system from 2.0.2 to 2.0.3 I log in as administrator and try to go to

```
System -> Web Setup Wizard
```

as instructed on the Magento official website. When I hit the link though, it takes me to a 404 Not Found page. This is how the setup wizard link looks like.

```
<a class="" href="http://mydomain/admin/admin/backendapp/redirect/app/setup/key/f047fc306175523b2836c6e5b72965ba2cc9bce0a36fb5c98f55d7ba5a4e4d55/">
<span>Web Setup Wizard</span>
</a>
```

What is the problem ? Even more strange, I found some ways to update from command line and when I run composer update I can see that it is downloading module/magento-base v 2.0.3 but after update is finished and I go to admin it still states v 2.0.2.  How should I upgrade the system ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108738/magento-2-update-2-0-3-note-in-backend-fail). Try my answer there, cleaning the var/cache/deployment to see if that allows you to run the upgrade. If that works I'd love to hear if you can set the upgrade in motion, because it keeps failing on my end without any errors.

Comment: nope, didn't solve it.

Comment: Hmm. Got any more info? What mode are you running the installation in? Are you sure the folder/file rights are correct? Are there any errors in the console.log? In the var/system.log and/or var/debug.log?

Comment: yes, I have set them to 777 just in case, i am running in developer mode

Comment: i found this in system.log   [2016-03-31 10:25:34] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'example.link' element cannot be added as child to 'header.links', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-03-31 10:25:34] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'example.link' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and '' respectively. [] []
[2016-03-31 10:25:34] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'store.settings.currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'store.settings' and 'header.panel' respectively.

Comment: Though I'm not sure these errors have anything to do with the rights, I do know it's not smart nor functional to just set everything to 777. There are some pretty specific settings needed for file ownership and permissions ( http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html ) - this could resolve some of the problems.

The broken reference errors sounds either like a failed upload or it needing a new deployment. Did you try switching to production mode and back again? This kicks in a lot of processing for all kinds of code and modules.

Comment: yeah, I know, I did all that, changed the 777 just in case for the purpose of the update and nope, haven't tried switching between dev and prod. Will try it.

Comment: Before upgrade,`var/di` and `var/generation` folders also need to be cleaned. But, your error of 404 is worrisome. Usually some error in application is 500. `404 not found` means a permission error or missing files. Can you verify that you have the `setup` folder in your magento root, and also it has the correct permissions? Also do you have the `update` folder?

Comment: We're currently replacing the 2.0.3 patch with a 2.0.4 patch due to some issues. Suggest you wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can using cmd it is work for me
Step By Step run following command

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.0.5 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
chmod -R 777 var
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```