# Magento 2 Update 2.0.3. note in Backend fail

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.0.3

When I login to my backend I get a white screen and an Update Message for 2.0.3.

The message can't be removed. Backend ist not working anymore. Magento 2 was in a password protected folder. I removed the password protection now. But it is still not working.

[image: Magento Community Edition 2.0.3 Includes Functional and Security Updates – 3/30/2016]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem. **It was a wrong location time in configuration.** Changing from to attributes was also not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem with your deployment/cache.
Try these steps;

- clear/delete the /var/ folder
- clear the cache (magento cache:clean via the CLI)
- run the magento setup:di:compile command via CLI

Then refresh the page, it should be working again. Most of the time these errors seem due to invalidated/corrupted or incomplete deployment of JavaScript files.

Edit: I had another similar issue today, where there were no errors of any kind. At last I found permission-related issues in the serverlogs. When I fixed the permissions, all was working again!

Comment: Thanks, the second 2 didn't help. Can I delete the whole var folder? Will it be created again?

Comment: But the first did the trick, or not?

Comment: No, I didn't try yet. Are you sure I can delete everithing in the var folder?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. This has always been possible in Magento1 and also Magento2. I've been deleting my /var/ folders every day for weeks now during development to fix these kinds of errors :)
All the /var/ container holds is session info, cacheing of files etc. Every time you delete this folder, you force Magento to regenerate all that stuff, fixing the most obvious errors like blank pages. Matter of fact, I had the same white-page a few minutes ago,

Comment: After that, if you still can't update, check this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108740/magento-2-cant-seem-to-upgrade-to-2-0-3/108748#108748

Comment: Unfortunathely t didn't help to delete the var folder. When I logged in this morning I got a message about a key change. But I can't do anything now as my backend does not work anymore.

Comment: And have you clear the cache and run the compile command after deleting the var folder? Maybe you can try switching to production mode first and rerunning these steps? That does the trick in my situation 99% of the time.

Your backend doesn't work, do you just get a blank screen? Are there any messages in the /var/system.log ?

Comment: Yes, the login screen was still finde, but after login in I just see the white page on my printscreen with the message and a 1 on the top right corner. Now I switched to production mode and back an now the frontend doesn't work anymore too:  Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled. 
#0 /home/zizzowa1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->assertMaintenance()
#1 /home/zizzowa1/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#2 {main} :-(

Comment: For the maitenance mode you can turn it off by deleting the maitenance.flag in the /var/ folder

Comment: I can't find  that file maintenance.flag in the var folder. I wait until my hoster restores the server from the backup. I hope it works after. I have only errors now.

Comment: Sorry, you where right, I forgot to refresh. The maintenance.flag was there and I could delete it. Thanks. But my backend is still not working.

Comment: Ok, I got the backup restored. But still after login it goes the the blank page with the update notification. I think I need to delete all and setup everything again :-(

Answer (score 0):

I spent 8 hours trying 1000 ways to delete the cache. But after login I still got the blank screen with the message. Finaly I removed everything on the server and installed all new again.

Comment: did this give solution?

Comment: Yes, but not very good for people with productive shops.