# Magento 2 - Can't seem to upgrade to 2.0.3

Tags: magento2, upgrade

Today [2.0.3 was released](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.0.3CE.html) and we've been trying out some Magento 2 installations on a development VPS.

There are multiple installations, but I can't seem to upgrade any of them.

At first we had some issues with the deployment, but after that had settled, every installation acts the same:

We open **System > Web Setup Wizard** and select **System Upgrade**.

After a few moments all we see is a error-box saying

> Sorry, we can't take that action right now

With no further errors/logs (nor in the console or syslogs).

I tried to do the same in production mode, hoping that would amount to anything, but alas..

Anyone else has problems running this update? Magento 2 has been a tough nut to crack so far with the server-settings and all, but we've managed to get it rolling smoothly, so I wonder why this isn't working.

Any ideas where to look for answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before system upgrade you have to setup **`System Configuration`**

[image]

You have to setup Public Access key and private access key from [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customerdata/secureKeys/list/)

[image]

Now you can do system upgrade.

If there will be any `cron setup` issue. Resolve to setup **cron**. [How to setup cron ?](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron)

Comment: Wow, how stupid of me to not think of this. Thanks! I'm trying it right away. 
Would be a plus for Magento to remind people of this in the error message, in stead of "nope, can't do it.".

Comment: is this necessary if you installed magento from archive ?

Comment: I am sorry, i don't have the meny System Config, I have the menu System and no Magento Marketplace

Comment: @Lachezer : Can you share the screenshot

Comment: http://imgur.com/Ft5DR7n

Comment: the link of Web Setup Wizard is redirtecting to a 404 Not Found Page as well...

Comment: Check permission of `var`, `pub` and `update`  folders