# Magento 2 Upgrade 404 Error (document root set to PUB folder)

Tags: magento2, upgrade

As I'm sure you are aware, there is a new version of Magento 2 (2.0.3 at the time of writing).

I can not follow the update instructions given in the Magento developer docs (using the [System Upgrade utility](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html)) as my document root points to the pub folder, not the main Magento installation folder. The setup wizard is not in the pub directory for security reasons and the best practice is to use the pub folder as the document root.

The only way I can think of using the setup wizard to upgrade the system is to change the doc root to the main Magento installation folder, upgrade the system, change the doc root back to the pub folder.

Does anyone know of any other work around or a way to upgrade with the setup wizard? I installed Magento via the command line using the compressed package (decompressed and installed via the command line tool)

Comment: GO to the  `System > Web Setup Wizard` and [check instruction](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108740/magento-2-cant-seem-to-upgrade-to-2-0-3)

Comment: @zedBlackbeard I am unable to reach the Web Setup Wizard because of the document root pointing to the PUB folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Magento install initially via the zip/gzip method, where pub is the document root, the procedure we're following to upgrade is:

1. Edit the composer.json file in the main directory, and change the "magento/product-community-edition" to 2.0.3
2. run: "composer update"
3. chmod a+x bin/magento
4. run: bin/magento setup:upgrade
5. run: bin/magento cache:flush

This seems to work well from what we've found so far. It's not officially documented in the dev guide, but seems to be an accepted method for now...

Comment: Perfect and thanks. This seems to have done the trick and just the kind of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade via Setup Wizard you need a separate document root setup for the Wizard, so you could access it.

Comment: This solution is a very good alternative to changing the document root for the main website. I didn't think about pointing a temporary sub domain to the main Magento folder. I went with the other answer though, as this seemed a better solution for me.

Comment: Sure. That's better option, if you have access to console.